# Should I specialise in a single job?

Tags: mobius-final-fantasy

I have unlocked the three starter jobs, and upgraded them to their first tier Ranger, Mage and Warrior.

I'm enjoying playing Warrior the most, as I'm having the most success with this job, but are there any reasons to spread my exp around and try to keep the various jobs up to level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, I want to clarify some things. The experience you earn simply applies to your player level. Jobs are improved by the elemental seeds you earn. As you go deeper into the jobs, abilities will begin needing more than one type of seed to unlock. While you can certainly get the seeds you need for a job by just playing that job exclusively (assuming the proper ability cards to earn those seeds), I wouldn't recommend playing only one job.

At some point, you're going to start finding encounters that are really tough for your Onion Knight, which draws fire, water, and stone elements. For instance, you'll at some point hit some encounters with a really strong wind or stone typed boss. The Onion Knight is not the optimal job for this boss because it either can't target the boss's weakness or it can't reduce the boss's damage through elemental drive resistances. The Neophyte Ranger would be a better class to use in this regard because it can draw elements for wind and stone and allow you to resist the boss's hardest hitting attacks and also deal extra damage by targeting it's weakness.

There are some other considerations, such as the basic stats that each job provides. Typically, Onion Knights have great attack, Apprentice Mages have great magic, and Neophyte Rangers have great break power. Optimizing these stats for a particular encounter is a little more involved and not really noticeable to the average player, but some players who optimize do account for it.

There are other considerations as well such as weapons or ability cards that you acquire. Keep in mind that ability cards for a particular class are more effective with that class, so if you have a lot of great mage ability cards, then your mage job may be a more effective choice over your warrior job. Weapons are job type specific, and can provide great stats and other passive benefits.

I suspect you're seeing more success with your warrior type job because you have a better weapon (the campaign provides a new sword for warriors in a chest early on) and potentially better ability cards for your warrior than your other job types. But at the end of the day, all three types of jobs essentially have the same game mechanics. The battle tactics between the jobs are largely the same. There's just a little variation in terms of stats and the elements that they can draw. So, pairing up a job with the particular boss you'll be encountering will eventually lead to more success, especially if you level up your other jobs as you go and unlock better passive abilities, ability cards, and weapons.

Comment: So it's more about maintaining a powerful deck of ability cards, and picking the job based on the enemies. Thanks for such an in-depth answer :)

Comment: Are more advanced roles in a job better? Is Hunter better than Ranger?

Comment: Are you talking about upgrading the Neophyte Ranger up to Hunter or drawing the Hunter job card from the job summon?

Comment: Unlocking a new job on an existing job card by completing a skill panel.

Comment: Then the answer is generally yes, mainly because you can continue to upgrade your stats. More attack, more magic, more hp, more starting elements, more resists, etc. The only exception might be the limit breaks, which will change a bit from job upgrade to job upgrade such as targeting or secondary effects. But I didn't really concern myself with that too much.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest focusing on 2 class types as later on during the story game you unlock a sub class to your deck meaning you can use 2 job types at your convenience during battles

Answer (score -3):

I would really just stick with one job, having a lot of others is too many. Though if you really want to use the others, you can. I'd just stick with one though.